# How to open External Login facebook,Twitter login window as popup in asp.net webform 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to use asp.net webform External login feature with website and i want to open login window as a popup so that when using click on Google, Facebook or twitter button it open the next page as popup not as the whole page which is the default behavior.

Below is the code for OpenAuthProvider.ascx user control not sure if any change is needed here

**Default code**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="OpenAuthProviders.ascx.cs" Inherits="OpenAuthProviders" %>

<div id="socialLoginList">
    <h4>Use another service to log in.</h4>
    <hr />
    <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="providerDetails" ItemType="System.String"
        SelectMethod="GetProviderNames" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <p>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="provider"  value="<%#: Item %>"
                    title="Log in using your <%#: Item %> account.">
                    <%#: Item %>
                </button>
            </p>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            <div>
                <p>There are no external authentication services configured. See <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=252803">this article</a> for details on setting up this ASP.NET application to support logging in via external services.</p>
            </div>
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
</div>
```

**Modified Code**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="OpenAuthProviders.ascx.cs" Inherits="OpenAuthProviders" %>

<div id="socialLoginList">
    <h4>Use another service to log in.</h4>
    <hr />
    <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="providerDetails" ItemType="System.String"
        SelectMethod="GetProviderNames" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <p>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="provider" onclick="window.open(this.href,'targetWindow',
                                   'toolbar=no,
                                    location=no,
                                    status=no,
                                    menubar=no,
                                    scrollbars=yes,
                                    resizable=yes,
                                    width=SomeSize,
                                    height=SomeSize');
 return false;" value="<%#: Item %>"
                    title="Log in using your <%#: Item %> account.">
                    <%#: Item %>
                </button>
            </p>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            <div>
                <p>There are no external authentication services configured. See <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=252803">this article</a> for details on setting up this ASP.NET application to support logging in via external services.</p>
            </div>
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
</div>
```

How can i make the facebook, twitter window open as popup